# I have several questions regarding to following PYTHON code segments.

Tags: python, python-2.4

*****Actually my question is how python automatically assign values to 'i' in following different python code segments.

```
data=[5,1,23,10]
datacount=len(data)
print ('value of datacount is',datacount)
for i in range(datacount-1):
    print ('value of i is',i)
    for k in range(i,datacount):
        print ('value of k is', k,'value of i is', i, 'value of datacount is', datacount)
        print(data)
        if data[i]>data[k]:
            temp=data[i]
            data[i],data[k]=data[k],temp
for i in range(datacount):
    print(data[i])
```

the result is:

```
>>> 
('value of datacount is', 4)
('value of i is', 0)
('value of k is', 0, 'value of i is', 0, 'value of datacount is', 4)
[5, 1, 23, 10]
('value of k is', 1, 'value of i is', 0, 'value of datacount is', 4)
[5, 1, 23, 10]
('value of k is', 2, 'value of i is', 0, 'value of datacount is', 4)
[1, 5, 23, 10]
('value of k is', 3, 'value of i is', 0, 'value of datacount is', 4)
[1, 5, 23, 10]
('value of i is', 1)
('value of k is', 1, 'value of i is', 1, 'value of datacount is', 4)
[1, 5, 23, 10]
('value of k is', 2, 'value of i is', 1, 'value of datacount is', 4)
[1, 5, 23, 10]
('value of k is', 3, 'value of i is', 1, 'value of datacount is', 4)
[1, 5, 23, 10]
('value of i is', 2)
('value of k is', 2, 'value of i is', 2, 'value of datacount is', 4)
[1, 5, 23, 10]
('value of k is', 3, 'value of i is', 2, 'value of datacount is', 4)
[1, 5, 23, 10]
1
5
10
23
>>>
```

consider the following code

```
data = [5,1,23,10,-3]
def fun(a):
    i,c=1,a[0]
    print ('value of i is', i)
    while i<len(a):
        print ('the value of len(a) is', len(a))
        if(a[i]>c):
            c=a[i]
            print ('the value of i is',i ,'the value of c is',c)
        i=i+1
    return i

print (fun(data))
```

result is:

```
>>> 
('value of i is', 1)
('the value of len(a) is', 5)
('the value of len(a) is', 5)
('the value of i is', 2, 'the value of c is', 23)
('the value of len(a) is', 5)
('the value of len(a) is', 5)
5
>>>
```

at any of above codes I did not assign value to 'i'. in first method it takes the value as 0, but second time it takes the value as 1. ok, now I edit this code as follows

now I do not pass any parameter to my method

```
def fun():
    i,c=1
    print ('value of i is', i)

    return i

print (fun())
```

it gives following error

```
    >>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e.s.kaushalya\Desktop\tempory\kk2", line 8, in -toplevel-
    print (fun())
  File "C:\Users\e.s.kaushalya\Desktop\tempory\kk2", line 3, in fun
    i,c=1
TypeError: unpack non-sequence
>>>
```

*****my question is I could not understand how python assigning values to 'i' in first two coding segments, and why python do not assign value to third coding 
segment?

Comment: Consider moving your actual question on top of the rest, so we can concentrate on your question while reading the code.

Comment: Also, do read [ask]. Stackoverflow is *not* a forum. And nobody cares or shoudl care that you're new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the first one:

```
for i in range(datacount-1):
    print ('value of i is',i)
```

By doing this `for...in...` loop, you are actually assigning a value to i.

Try this

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    print i
```

Then you'll understand.

The second one:

```
i,c = 1, a[0]
```

What you're doing is called **tuple unpacking**. Simply speaking, it will make `i = 1` and `c = a[0]`. Check out python doc for more details.

Together with the third one, if you do it this way:

```
i,c = 1, 2
```

You will have `i = 1` and `c = 2`.

Comment: Ok... now i understand wot u said... thank you very much

Comment: @E.S.Kaushalya Glad to help. You can accept this answer if you think it's OK.